can $\int \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^4}}dx$ be expressed in terms of elementary functions?
I'm trying to evaluate this integral:
$$\int \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x^4}}dx$$
After a little substitution, the integral can be shown to be equivalent to
$$\int \sqrt{\cosh(2\alpha)}\,d\alpha,$$
which can be expressed as an elliptic integral, but I was wondering whether it can be expressed using only elementary functions?

Probably can't be done, instead, $\int \sqrt[4]{1+\frac1{x^4}},\mathrm{d}x$ can be expressed by elementary functions.

Check against the general result (from Hardy's book, but not due to Hardy) in this MSE answer.

If it could, then the incomplete elliptic integral function $E$ could be expressed in terms of elementary functions, but it can't be.

Maybe it was meant to be : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4107897/how-should-i-solve-int-frac1x-sqrt1-frac1x4-dx?noredirect=1

I'll address the more general question of which indefinite integrals of the form
$$\int \sqrt[n]{1 + x^m} \,dx$$
admit an elementary closed form, where $m$ is an integer and $n$ is a nonzero integer. This question turns out to be a special case of the work of Chebyshev (see p. 51 of Hardy's Integration of Functions of a Single Variable, which Dave L. Renfro mentioned in a comment).
First, provided $m \neq 0$, substituting $t = x^m$ transforms the integral to
$$\frac1m \int t^{\frac{1-m}m} (1 + t)^{\frac1n} \,dt .$$
Now, Chebyshev's condition says that the integrand has a closed-form (in Hardy's language, "finite form") antiderivative if and only if at least one of $\frac{1 - m}m, \frac1n, \frac{1 - m}m + \frac1n$ are integers. (For the integrand in the question statement, $\sqrt{1 + \frac1{x^4}}$, these numbers are $-\frac54, \frac12, -\frac34$, so it admits no elementary antiderivative). The first is an integer if and only if $m = \pm 1$, the second is an integer if and only if $n = \pm 1$, and the third is an integer if and only if $m = n = \pm 1$, $m = n = \pm2$, or $m = -n$. So, the only elementary cases are:

$m = -1$, when the substitution $1 + t = u^n$ rationalizes the integral, giving
$$\int \sqrt[n]{1 + \frac1x} \,dx = -n \int \frac{u^n \,du}{(u^n - 1)^2},$$
$m = 0$, when the integrand is a constant
$m = 1$, when the integrand is a power of a linear function,
$n = \pm 1$, when the integrand is a rational function,
$m = n = -2$, when the integral is $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + \frac1{x^2}}} = \sqrt{1 + x^2} + C,$$
$m = n = 2$, when the integral is
$$\int \sqrt{1 + x^2} \,dx = \frac12 \operatorname{arsinh} x + \frac12 x \sqrt{1 + x^2} + C,$$ and
$m = -n$, when the substitution $1 + t = t u^n$ rationalizes the integral, giving
$$\int \sqrt[n]{1 + \frac{1}{x^n}} \,dx = \int \frac{u^n \,du}{u^n - 1}.$$

Remark It follows from the definition that the functions considered in this answer have a closed-form antiderivative in terms of the Gauss Hypergeometric function, ${}_2 F_1$: When $m \neq 0, n \neq 0$,
$$\int \sqrt[n]{1 + x^m} \,dx = x {}_2 F_1 \left(\frac1m, -\frac1n; 1 + \frac1m; -x^m\right) + C .$$

What is the expression of the integral in terms of elliptical integral, because when I put it in wolfram it only expressed it as Gauss Hypegeometric function https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sqrt%281%2B1%2Fx%5E4%29+dx as you’ve derived here

Maple returns this mess (which can be simplified a little) https://i.imgur.com/9yVLPNz.png The integral can also be expressed in terms of the incomplete beta function. I don't see immediately how OP reduced the problem to evaluating $\int \sqrt{\cosh 2 \alpha} ,d\alpha$.

Another way to arrive to @Travis Willse's more general result.
$$I=\int \sqrt[n]{1 + x^m} \,dx$$
$$x^m=t \quad \implies \quad I=\frac 1m \int t^{\frac{1}{m}-1} (1+t)^{\frac{1}{n}}\,dt$$
$$(1+t)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{n}}{k}\,t^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}
{\Gamma (k+1)\, \Gamma\left(-k+\frac{1}{n}+1\right)}\,t^k$$
$$I=\frac{\Gamma
   \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{m}\int\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{k+\frac{1}{m}-1}}{\Gamma (k+1)\,\Gamma \left(-k+\frac{1}{n}+1\right)}\,dt$$
$$I=\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\, t^{\frac 1 m}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^{k}}{(k m+1) \,\Gamma (k+1)\, \Gamma
   \left(-k+\frac{1}{n}+1\right)}$$ which is the definition of a Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I=t^{\frac{1}{m}} \,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{m},-\frac{1}{n};\frac{m+1}{m};-t\right)$$ Go back to $x$ to obtain  @Travis Willse's last formula.
